# Linking errors when using proto tutorial

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using c++ in ubuntu with apatana as my IDE.

I compiled the addressbook.proto file as follows:

```
protoc -I=/home/workspace/rtb/src/ --cpp_out=/home/workspace/rtb/src/ /home/workspace/rtb/src/addressbook.proto
```

I then included the output header file into my c++ code as follows:

```
#include "addressbook.pb.h"
```

That should be it.  Right?

When I build...I get a list of errors that that is too long list.  below is the last few lines.  What am I missing?  How do I use proto buffers in c++?

```
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial11AddressBookE[vtable for tutorial::AddressBook]+0x40): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial11AddressBookE[vtable for tutorial::AddressBook]+0x48): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial11AddressBookE[vtable for tutorial::AddressBook]+0x88): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial11AddressBookE[vtable for tutorial::AddressBook]+0x90): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial6PersonE[vtable for tutorial::Person]+0x20): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial6PersonE[vtable for tutorial::Person]+0x40): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial6PersonE[vtable for tutorial::Person]+0x48): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial6PersonE[vtable for tutorial::Person]+0x88): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial6PersonE[vtable for tutorial::Person]+0x90): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[vtable for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x20): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[vtable for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x40): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[vtable for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x48): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(google::protobuf::MessageLite const&)'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[vtable for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x88): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::DiscardUnknownFields()'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTVN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[vtable for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x90): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::SpaceUsed() const'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTIN8tutorial11AddressBookE[typeinfo for tutorial::AddressBook]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTIN8tutorial6PersonE[typeinfo for tutorial::Person]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./src/addressbook.pb.o:(.rodata._ZTIN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberE[typeinfo for tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rtb] Error 1
```

Comment: Those are linking errors.Make sure you are linking to the library.

Comment: solved:  I had to add -lprotobuf

Answer (score 6):

You have to link your code to the protocol buffers library. Most likely, the flag you need is 
`-l protobuf`.

Comment: actually i am running tryProto.cpp file as: g++ -l protobuf tryProto.cpp  and still getting the same error, adding  -lprotobuf has not made any difference, is there anything i am missing